# Thymeleaf not displaying values from spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, template-engine, thymeleaf

I am practising thymeleaf template engine for the first time. I have followed the tutorial and so on but I have no idea where I am going wrong.

My controller:

```
public String mainPage(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("data", "Hello Thymeleaf");  
    return "main";
}
```

and my html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
   <h1>th:text="${data}"</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit localhost it displays th:text="${data}" instead of Hello Thymeleaf

```
<h1>"${data}"</h1>
```

doesn't work either. View resolver config must be correct as it resolves main to main.html. I am using spring4 SpringTemplateEngine and spring4 thymeleaf view resolver.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `th:text`

```
 <h1 th:text="${data}"></h1>
```

or if you don't want to use the `th:text` attribute, then you have to use `th:inline="text"` and make the thymeleaf render the context inside the tag. But make sure you put the variable inside `[[` and `]]`

```
 <h1 th:inline="text">[[${data}]]</h1>
```

Comment: I didn't realised you and chrylis answered before my edit. thanks I had the th:text= on the wrong side of >

Answer (score 3):

Thymeleaf isn't Velocity or Freemarker and doesn't replace expressions blindly. You need the expression in an appropriate tag attribute, such as

```
<h1 data-th-text="${data}" />
```

Answer (score -4):

remove quotes to "${data}" and just use ${data}. I also agree with @Faraj Farook