# Thymeleaf not displaying values in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf. I have a spring-boot project where I am trying to display some attributes value which has been set from spring controller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Thymeleaf");
    return "info";
    }
}
```

Please find below my info.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:thm="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Info</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1 thm:text="${message}"></h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please find below my pom.xml file [dependencies only]

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I know there are few post in **stackoverflow regarding this topic** I have already gone through few of them as listed below:

[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569682/thymeleaf-not-displaying-values-from-spring-controller)
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100739/why-thymeleafs-thtext-not-working-in-my-spring-project)

I have accordingly modified my html page as per suggestion from stackoverflow blogs. But still the problem persist.

My web page is not renedering the Thymeleaf text at all.
Can anyone figureout the exact issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thm` is not a valid prefix in Thymleaf, use `<h1 th:text="${message}"></h1>` instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But can you please explain why we cann't use thm as prefix,for other frameworks like struts,spring form tag there is no as such bound on prefix name.

Comment: Sorry, I can not answer this question since `Thymeleaf` is the only template engine I have ever used... You can refer this to check more about Thymeleaf syntaxes...https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

You can first retrieve it from the Model object that you are sending and then you can use it by using `th:each` and then `th:value`.

```
 <div th:each="message : ${message}">
   <h1 th:text="${message}"></h1>
 </div>
```